# Leading zeros are truncated when I spool to CSV

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, csv

I have spooled a file to CSV using sqlplus. Everything works great but there is one  issue. I have mobile numbers which start with 0, for example 04589 and 02586.

After the spooling is complete, 0s are truncated and the end results are 4589 and 2586.

I want the output to display in CSV as:

```
04589
02586
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information for a meaningful answer. What is the column data type? What does your query look like? When you view query results in SQL*Plus, how do the look? You're not opening the CSV file in Excel, are you?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs more details but has been abandoned by the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String are written between `""` in the CSV. So your datatype is not string type, or the tool you use for viewing the CSV automatically converts and trims it.

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus -S bp/bp
set markup csv on
set echo off
spool 1.csv
select '04589' as phone from dual
union all select '02586' from dual;

"PHONE"
"04589"
"02586"

exit
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat 1.csv

"PHONE"
"04589"
"02586"

[oracle@o71 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to achieve this:

concatenate your column, which has leading zero, with prefix `CHR(28)` and you are done.

e.g.

```
spool file1.csv
select numbercol from dual;
select CHR(28)||numbercol from table;
spool off;
```

`CHR(28)` is an invisible char representation of a ASCII value.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me when exporting/importing to csv while keeping my leading zeros is using LPad and length in unison. It might slow down larger queries but I found it to be useful.

```
''||trim(LPad(ColumnName,LENGTH(ColumnName),0))||''
```

Comment: This is quite terse; your answer could be more valuable if it explained why this piece of code addressed the OP's requirements.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an Oracle issue.
It's an Excel issue, unfortunately.
I've looked high and low for the answer myself with zero success.
I have tried formatting the column in the spreadsheet, but at that point, the horse has left the barn so to speak.

Comment: In some circumstances Excel can be the issue when converting/opening CSV files, but without more information/details, it's hard to make that assumption.

Comment: True. Opening the csv in a plain-text editor will yield the proper formatting.  My personal experience shows that opening in MS Excel truncates the leading zero.

Comment: It's possible that writing the number out in double quotes (from Oracle to CSV) would make Excel load it as text.

Answer (score -2):

In Excel:  Data>Import from CSV (rather than just double-clicking the CSV file to open it).

Comment: @Ryan - please register your account - that will give you the ability to login on multiple devices and receive notifications from the site etc.  Also, please take the [tour] - thanks!

Comment: Regarding your answer, how does this prevent the .csv data export from dropping leading zeros on numbers?